# Search a file with a particular pattern using tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to search for a file of following pattern:

```
debug_abc_xyz_123_$times
```

or

```
debug_ad_kdsfj_da_$times
```

where this `times` is a variable which I get from the user and is of the form:

```
yyyymmdd-hhmmss-IST
```

This doesn't work:

```
set fh [open debug_*_$times r]
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm) to get a list of those files that follow this pattern (below, the file must be in the same directory as the script; use `-directory` and give the path otherwise):

```
set files [glob debug_*_$times]
```

Once you get this, you can go through the list and open one. Now, I don't know what file you want to open if there are more so I will assume there is only one.

```
set fh [open $files r]
```

As Hoodiecrow rightly mentioned, if the file name contains characters that can break the above code it's better to use `lindex` file:

```
set fh [open [lindex $files 0] r]
```

---

If you want to get the latest file, you can use `file mtime` and a loop to help:

```
set latest_file ""
set latest_date 0
foreach file $files {
     set mtime [file mtime $file]
     if {$mtime > $latest_date} {
         set latest_date $mtime
         set latest_file $file
     }
}
set fh [open $latest_file r]
```

If you have several files with the same modified date, the above will open the first in the order they were `glob`bed.

Comment: No no.. i had generated many files with the above given timestamp appended at the end. So I just needed to search for the file based on the timestamp and the patten. The first solution worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @aro Oh duh lol. Forgot about that. Won't hurt to keep it here now. You're welcome!

Comment: Note that even if there is only one file in the list, using the file list as an argument to `open` can fail if the file name contains spaces or other characters that can't stand unquoted in lists. It's better to use `open [lindex $files 0]` even if `[llength $files] == 1`.